# How to specify content of fat jar in MANIFEST.MF?

Tags: java, maven, jar

Is there a standard way for `MANIFEST.MF` to have a list of all jars which where merged into a specific fat-jar?

For example, `foo` and `bar` are part of the jar:

```
Fat-Jar: foo-1.2, bar-2.3
```

Comment: AFAK, fat-jar doesn't contain individual jars but all classes in exploded format

Comment: If the objective is to document the JAR dependencies, then a fat jar builder such as Maven Shade will include your pom.xml in the fat jar (in the `META-INF` for your package). Otherwise I am not aware of any standard way to document this in a manifest.

Comment: Fat jars is a hack for solving the problem that java cannot use jars in jars. Hacks don’t have standards.

Comment: The first question which comes into my mind: Why do you need those entries in the manifest if you have all jars (exploded) within the resulting fat jar? What kind of purpose does those entries have?